# widgets_init cause fatal error

Tags: wordpress

Hi am new to wp and i am trying to create my first widget

i have follow the instructions and same samples i have found but my problem is that that its not working when place to plugin folder.

I have create a folder foo in the plugins folder and inside i have place the widget.php
in my functions.php i have

```
function register_foo_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );
```

but when execute i get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Foo_Widget' not found in /home/wordpress/public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 324
```

Now if i go to my theme folder create a folder inc and place the widget.php inside
and at my functions.php change the path its working

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widget.php';
register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
```

As far as i know the plugin is the default folder for the widgets and the class actually extends WP_Widget

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `Foo_Widget` needs to be defined, and needs to be a `class` instance...Please [read the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget). There's a great example there.

Comment: @mevius It is defined and its working fine if i change the path to my theme, but if i dont fails

Comment: I see...Can you edit your question with your widget class?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time digging into to building a widget, use this: https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Widget-Boilerplate

Without seeing further code, it's hard to assist.